# AngularJS - Watch filtered list for changes

Tags: angularjs, watch

Within angular I have a filtered list of people that takes the filter criteria from a predicate function. I want to watch a variable of the filtered list (called filteredPeople) every time the filtered list changes. But I am unable to see when that variable changes.

My code is below:

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="person in ($ctrl.filteredPeople = ($ctrl.people | filter: $ctrl.filter))">
      ...
    </li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
controller: ['$scope',
    function ($scope) {
        var $ctrl = this;

        $ctrl.people = {...}
        $ctrl.filteredPeople = [];


        $scope.$watch($ctrl.filteredPeople, function () {
           console.log("called"); //not being called 
        });

        $ctrl.filter = function (p) {
           //custom filter function for each item in the array of people
        }

      }]
```

I can answer any questions of provide more code if needed

Comment: $watchCollection does what you need, but actually what are you doing is very bad... Better update list manually in controller - expressions like '$ctrl.people | filter: $ctrl.filter' looks nice, but are slow and buggy.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov Il do that. Sounds like a better idea for the end goal I am trying to accomplish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.items = [
    { name: 'Sam' },
    { name: 'Max' },
    { name: 'Tom' },
    { name: 'Henry' },
    { name: 'Jack' },
    { name: 'Kate' }
  ]
  var counter = 1;
  $scope.$watchCollection('vm.filtered', function(){
    console.log('Changed' + counter++);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js">
</script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='ctrl as vm'>
  <input type='text' ng-model='vm.filter' />
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat='item in vm.filtered = (vm.items | filter : vm.filter)'>{{item}}</li>
  </ul>  
</div>
```